# Entity Framework One To One using Third table

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-5

Here are my models

```
public class A
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
    public int BId { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public A A { get; set; }
}
public class AB
{
    public int AId { get; set; }
    public int BId { get; set; }
}
```

How Can I write fluent api to map A to B as one to one relationship using Entity Framework 5 code first?

Comment: What is the purpose of `AB`.

Comment: @TrippKinetics it looks like an association table

Comment: @TrippKinetics this is legacy project I cant change architecture of database

Comment: @TrippKinetics  database first model somehow handles this case, it isn't event generating AB table in edmx.